# T is not a class but it is

Tags: c++, templates

Why this doesn't work? (For hell's sake!)

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;
public:
    A();
};
```

I'm getting following error:
**Error 1   error C2825: 'T': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::**

But T is a class, I've just specified that didn't I? So what's the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code where you use this template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`T` could be a primitive type, depending on how you instantiate the template...

Comment: thanks, I didn't see that in declaration I've had A<int>. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In which template specialization are you getting this error? Maybe you are doing something like `A<int>` somewhere in the code. Please give more information about the specialization that gives the error if you want better information.

Answer (score 2):

The 'class' keyword has a different meaning when used to specify a template type parameter. In fact, `template<class T>` and `template <typename T>` are completely equivilent, and T can be just about any type. Writing `template<class T>` in no way tells the compiler that T shall be only a class type.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI: Visual C++ only throws such an error if encountering a related problem when actually creating a concrete class from a template. You should be able to determine where that happened rather easily from the error message, and looking into that code might get you a long way to fixing such problems.